# Writing to FileStream works, MemoryStream copied to FileStream doesn't

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I have some code that used a FileStream, StreamWriter and XmlDocument to produce Excel-compatible output files. Very useful!

However I now have a need to make copies of the file, and I'd like to do that in-memory. So I took my original FileStream code and changed the FileStream to a MemoryStream, and then wrapped that in this function:

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Friend Sub Save(Optional ByVal SaveCalculatedResults As Boolean = True)
    Dim MStream As MemoryStream
    Dim FStream As FileStream
    Dim Bytes As Byte()

    'make the stream containing the XML
    MStream = ToXLSL(SaveCalculatedResults)
    If MStream.Length = 0 Then Return

    'then read that data into a byte buffer
    ReDim Bytes(CInt(MStream.Length))
    MStream.Read(Bytes, 0, CInt(MStream.Length))

    'and then write it to "us"
    FStream = New FileStream("C:\OUTFILE.XLSX", FileMode.Create)
    FStream.Write(Bytes, 0, CInt(MStream.Length))
    FStream.Flush()
End Sub
```

This creates a file in the correct location, it has the exact same length as it did before, but opening it in Excel causes an error about the file format being invalid.

Can anyone see any obvious problems in that code? Perhaps I am writing the bytes backwards? Is this possibly a text encoding problem? 32/64 problem?

p.s. I tried using CopyTo, but that doesn't seem to work in VB?

Comment: Hmmm, replacing CopyTo (which doesn't exist?) with WriteTo solves the problem. No idea why it should do that, but it does so I'm happy!

Comment: You could write directly to the output stream

Answer (score 2):

It requires guessing what ToXLSL() does but the behavior gives a strong hint: the MemoryStream's Position is located at the end of the stream.  So the Read() call doesn't actually read anything.  Verify by checking its return value.

Just get rid of Bytes() entirely, it is very wasteful to duplicate the data like this.  You don't need it, the MemoryStream already gives you access to the data:

```
Using FStream = New FileStream("C:\OUTFILE.XLSX", FileMode.Create)
    FStream.Write(MStream.GetBuffer(), 0, CInt(MStream.Length))
End Using
```

Do note that the *Using* statement is *not* optional.  And that you cannot write to C:\